# using a if statement as my type guard but tpescript ignores it

Tags: typescript

```js
const datas = {
    a: {
        "0": 0,
        "1": 1
    },
    b: {
        "0": 0
    }
}

function index (data:keyof typeof datas, prop: "0"|"1") {
    if(prop in datas[data]) {
        return datas[data][prop] // <- this line errors
    }
}
```

```js
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"0" | "1"' can't be used to index type '{ "0": number; "1": number; } | { "0": number; }'.
  Property '1' does not exist on type '{ "0": number; "1": number; } | { "0": number; }'.ts(7053)
```

as you can see i have a if statement to check if the property `prop` exists in `datas[data]` so i can access the data. however for some reason typescript just ignored it

Comment: @Dai That isn't what the error is about - it is saying that you can't use `prop` to index into `datas[data]`.

Comment: Also, you should enable strict-mode and disable implicit-any.

Comment: @Dai 1) i did enable strict mode 2) using typeof to check does not help with anything

Comment: I was wrong, I deleted my comment :)

Comment: Can this function return undefined? `index("b", "1")` would return undefined at runtime. Are you trying to reflect this in the types or are you trying to prevent this with the type system?

Comment: well in theory it should not provide the parameter that would cause it to invalidate the if statement. The code above is just a simplified version of my actual code

Comment: So are you looking for something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9nzVm)?

Comment: let me implement this to my actual code

Answer (score 0):

To validate the parameters at compile time, you'll need to change your function to be generic:

```
function index<K extends keyof typeof datas>(data: K, prop: keyof typeof datas[K]) {
```

and inside, we need a variable so TypeScript can keep track of what is being narrowed:

```
const value = datas[data];

if (prop in value) {
    return value[prop];
}
```

Then `prop` can only be a valid key based on what was given to `data`.

```
index("a", "0");
index("a", "1");
index("b", "0");
index("b", "1"); // bad, since datas.b[1] doesn't exist
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N9nzVm)